# Angular JS app takes 3 minutes to load on Internet Explorer browser

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat, internet-explorer-11

**Background:**

I have built a tool using angularjs. The user is able to view a dynamic page based on the data. The page can be really long with lots of various types of fields within it. There are many  and various angularjs components used within the app.

**Issue:**

If a user has got lots of data (which is shown within various input fieds/date fields etc; around 500 fields ) then the page takes around 3 minutes to load in IE browser (IE11 is my browser). **The same page loads within 20 seconds on chrome and firefox.** I have tried now almost a month to find the issue ..but still no luck.

I am very desperate for a solution. I coudn't find any tool that would show me what is causing my page to take so long to load.

Comment: Why don't you implement pagination or similar techniques for loading some data the user can immediately see, then more data as the page is scrolled?

Furthermore, what do the IE dev tools say in regard to network, DOM flame graph, etc?

Comment: my application is designed to work as a single page app with lots of show/hides based on user responses to questions and answers. So I can't use pagination to split the ui as multiple pages. I can see two tabs in my IE dev tool (profiler & Memory) , but the information that it provides doesn't make any sense to me...or i don't know how to use it

Comment: Check out the article that I linked to in my answer - I think it will help. In the article it also references an npm package that could sort out your issue with the ng-repeat issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first things first, you'll need to profile what is actually taking so long. I suggest you check out

https://github.com/angular/batarang

to do this. A good article that goes over it's use is available at http://daginge.com/technology/2013/08/11/debugging-performance-problems-in-angularjs-with-batarang/ -

It's too long to include in this answer, but the general flow of resolving this is probably going to involve streamlining the watchers involved in each of those component fields etc - rendering 500 fields at once seems somewhat unnecessary - pagination would probably be an easy fix. Limit the data to maybe 50 fields per page? You'll need to track if it's the actual queries you're running to get the data that is taking so long, although based on the difference betweeen IE and Chrome, I would guess it's going to be something in the browser. It could also be that IE is being forced to use some polyfills for the functionality that Chrome and FF are supplying natively. Maybe link to your repo for us to have a look at?

Comment: Thanks, i am going through the article you have recommended